# Create a DLL and integrate with an RPA tool

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0

I need to create a dll and then integrate it with an RPA tool.
So for creating the DLL, if I create it targetting .net standard 2.0, which .net framework will I need on my computer to be able to run it? Can it be either .net framework or .net core framework? I know .net standard is not a runtime, but little confused with its use here.
Also, what should be my best bet to develop a DLL which can be used futher with any other tool.

Answer (score 1):

With our Automation Anywhere platform, you can integrating a C# DLL into a metabot.  You can then access the methods in the C# code by bots.

A Metabot can encapsulate assets and logic for common processes and tasks that can be reused by other bots.  A Metabot can thus be used as library of functions that can be reused in other Tasks.  This avoids the need to create the same functionality in each bot.

To encapsulate logic in Metabot, perform the following: 
• Create a DLL which performs the respective function. 
• Add DLL as an Asset in Metabot designer. 
• Add Logic to perform the operation. 
• Use the Metabot function to perform same task.

Comment: Thanks @bfoley. I understand that. My doubt was basically about the .net framework

Comment: Generally DLLs compile all the appropriate resource into a single executable. So long as the DLL is standalone, you should be able to use any variation on the .NET framework